# XML XSLT namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I got an xml file with namespace 'tns'. I want to use an xslt without to use 'tns' everywhere, but use a matching template instead with the tns namespace declared once and use that one. I want to match the root tns:cv (xml) to my root cv (xsl) Whats wrong with my xslt, because it displays the xml elements, but not the content in it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="multiLanguageToSingle.xslt"?>
<tns:cv xmlns:tns="http://www.i8c.be/CvService/1.0">
    <tns:generalLanguage>nl</tns:generalLanguage>
    <tns:careerPath>
        <tns:current>
            <tns:company language="nl">
                <tns:companyName></tns:companyName>
                <tns:description></tns:description>
            </tns:company>
        </tns:current>
        <tns:former>
            <tns:company language="nl">
                <tns:companyName></tns:companyName>
                <tns:description></tns:description>
            </tns:company>
        </tns:former>
    </tns:careerPath>
    <tns:companyDetails>
        <tns:address>
```

I want to use an xsl for the above xml (first few lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="http://www.i8c.be/CvService/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tns:cv" />
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/tns:cv">
<cv xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.i8c.be/CvService/1.0 cvDataTemplate.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:variable name="language" select='"nl"'/>
    <careerPath>
        <current>
        <xsl:for-each select="cv/careerPath/current/company[@language=$language]">
            <companyName><xsl:value-of select="companyName"/></companyName>
            <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/></description>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </current>

        <former>
        <xsl:for-each select="cv/careerPath/former/company[@language=$language]">
            <companyName><xsl:value-of select="companyName"/></companyName>
            <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/></description>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </former>
    </careerPath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to realize about namespaces is that the namespace in your XML file is not really the `tns` thing – that is only a file-local name/abbreviation for the actual namespace, namely, `http://www.i8c.be/CvService/1.0`. Now, you have chosen the same abbreviation in your xslt file (which makes sense for readability, but is completely optional as far as the tools are concerned). Thus, you cannot expect `cv/careerPath/current/company[@language=$language]` to match anything, and for two reasons:

- There is no `careerPath` element in the default namespace in your XML file. That would need to be `tns:careerPath`, and similar for the other components of your XPath string.
- You are asking for the match with your topmost `tns:cv` element already being the context node, by wirtue of being inside an `xsl:tenplate` match on it. Since that node does not contain a `cv` child, an XPath starting with `cv/` results in the empty node set.

So, remove the `cv/` at the beginning of your queries and either

- add namespace qualifiers or
- change the default namespace in your XSLT file, by putting `xmlns="http://www.i8c.be/CvService/1.0"` on some sufficiently far out element. (Note that this also affects unqualified element names for your output.)